# How to get inner html of div in Vaadin Flow while contenteditable is active

Tags: java, vaadin-flow

I have got a problem with Vaadin Flow. I would like to create a simple text editor on my own website. I created a simple div component with element attribute contenteditable set on true. On client side, website user edit div and after pressing the button I would like to receive inner html of div on java server side. The code below does not provide that functionality.

```
Button button = new Button();
Div div = new Div();
div.getElement().setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    System.out.println(div.getText());
});
```

May I use polymer template? Please help me solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility of using `div.getElement().setProperty("innerHTML", html);`. If you use this, please note that setting the `innerHtml` property will change some behaviour of the element, it will no longer manage it's child elements.

> The "innerHTML" property has an impact on the descendants structure of
>   the element. So setting the "innerHTML" property removes all the
>   children.
>   -- [from documentation](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/12.0.3/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Element.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Another possibility is `div.getElement().getOuterHtml();` except that returns the outer HTML. Still worth mentioning here.

On a sidenote, you might also be interested in [this editor component](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/juicyaceeditor/overview).